# Como centralizar o reCaptcha do Google?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

Tenho um reCaptcha no meu formulário, mas não estou conseguindo centralizar ele ou deixar no mesmo tamanho dos campos.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                 ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="">
                    ...
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cargo*:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="minha_key"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso arrumar isso?

Comment: Está usando bootstrap? Coloca um pouco mais do seu HTML aí para ficar mais fácil de entender.

Comment: Estou sim @Ricardo. Coloquei mais uma parte do código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div do recaptcha é um display block, para centralizar vc adiciona um width na div e um margin: auto.

```
.g-recaptcha {
  width: 302px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Show, funcionou!